# P vs NP and Gödel

Tags: logic, computer-science, incompleteness

I apologize for the, perhaps, silly question. My impression, as a layman, is that Gödel Incompleteness Theorem should rule out the possibility that P=NP. Is that true or there are deeper technical implications?

Comment: What makes you say that? (If that were true, why would people be offering a million dollars to resolve the question?)

Comment: I don't see the point in cross posting both MO and MSE at the same time, given a few days of wait and nothing would have come up on MO (or vice versa) it would be reasonable to cross post.

Comment: Also, being a layman or not you should at least explain why this seems that way to you.

Comment: As an interesting aside, Godel wrote a letter to Von Neumann once expressing how, if P=NP, it will be the end of human mathematics, excepting possibly the postulation of axioms. The remark is in [this paper](http://www.scottaaronson.com/blog/?p=735) (which is well worth a read for most folks here anyway).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'll repeat what I wrote over on MO:

It is true that there is no algorithm to determine whether or not $T$ is proved by PA, and that the proof of this is pretty close to the proof of Godel's theorem. If there were a polynomial $p$  such that every theorem of length $K$  had a proof of length $p(K)$, this would contradict the above fact. (Just trying every proof of length $p(K)$  would be an algorithm.)

It is also true that, if P=NP, there is a polynomial time algorithm such that, if $T$ has a proof of length $N$, then this algorithm finds a proof of length $q(N)$, for some polynomial $q$.

These two facts are not in contradiction, because the first is about proofs of length polynomial in the size of the **theorem**, and the second is about proofs polynomial in the size of **some other proof**.

Answer (score 5):

There is no reason to think that the incompleteness theorems have any bearing on the question whether $P=NP$, and no current work has established any relationship between them.

Answer (score 2):

Diagonalization worked well for Gödel's theorem, but the quest to use it to resolve the *P* versus *NP* question has been ruled out by the [Baker-Gill-Solovay theorem](http://people.csail.mit.edu/madhu/ST05/scribe/lect02.ps).