# Decidability of $P = NP$?

Tags: np-complete, conjectures

*(Please, don't sign this as duplicate of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/36912/p-vs-np-and-g%C3%B6del) question, they are not.)*

Is it possible, that the well-known $P=NP$ conjecture is undecidable in ZFC?

Is there any result about this topic?

Comment: Relevant MO thread: [Independence of P = NP?](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/50023/independence-of-p-np)

Comment: Theoretical computer science can help you. And see this:http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/10044/implications-of-unprovability-of-p-neq-np